# Modify exported variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, global-variables

I have a shell-script that looks like the following code snippet:

```
...
export updates=0

processFiles() {
    updates=$((updates+1))
}

export -f processFiles
find $path -exec /bin/bash -c "processFiles '{}'" \;

echo $updates
```

The use is to count the amount of updates, inserts and files to keep. Unfortunately the last echo always prints 0.

I have already tried to use export in the function as well - didn't work.

Comment: The variable `updates` is modified in a child process. The parent process will never see its modifications. Now tell us what you're trying to achieve, maybe there's another solution that will be more efficient than the one you're trying.

Comment: The goal is to print a little "statistic" after the script has finished. processFiles does either keep a file as is, insert a new one or update an existing one. After all files have been processed i want to know the number each operation took place. This statistic is printed after the find finished its duty, thus its not possible to do this in the processFiles function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `find`, you can use bash directly, provided your search criteria are simple enough. E.g.,

```
for file in *; do
    processFiles "$file"
done
```

will execute the function `processFiles` on all files and directories of the current directory (except the hidden ones) with argument the name of each file and directory. If you need to apply it recursively to all files and directories and subdirectories (except the hidden ones), use the globstar shell option:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

updates=0

processFiles() {
    ((++updates))
}

for file in **; do
    processFiles "$file"
done

echo "$updates"
```

If you just want files, and no directories, insert this in the for loop:

```
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
```

which will continue the loop if `file` is not a file (i.e., if it's something else, like a directory).

To match only files in a directory obtained by expanding the variable `path`, write your for loop thus:

```
for file in "$path"/*; do
```

(or `"$path"/**` if you're using globstar and want recursion).

If you need more complex search criteria, you can always use `extglob` option. If you need to also include the hidden files, use the `dotglob` option.

You'll find more info about bash in the reference manual, and in particular these sections:

- Shopt builtin: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin
- Pattern Matching: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching
- Conditional Expressions: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

One last note: If you really don't like this 100% bash solution and if you still want to do something along the script in your OP, then don't use bash variables, but use a (temporary) file instead to store the values you need to pass from one process to another. This is a cheap IPC method that works pretty well, but that is more difficult to implement safely.

Comment: I really like that solution! There is now only one thing left: the for loop does start when the last file is found. Is it possible to modify this solution such that the function is performed right when the file is found (like find -exec does)?

Comment: @Lorunification I have no idea whether it's possible or not... in fact, I really doubt it's possible; but maybe someone cleverer will come up with a better (simple) solution.